# How to read variating data into dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to extract the name of the constants and their corresponding `values` from a `.txt` file into a `dictionary`. Where `key = NameOfConstants` and `Value=float`.

The start of the `file` looks like this:

```
speed of light             299792458.0        m/s
gravitational constant     6.67259e-11        m**3/kg/s**2
Planck constant            6.6260755e-34      J*s
elementary charge          1.60217733e-19     C
```

How do I get the `name` of the constants easy?

This is my attempt:

```
with open('constants.txt', 'r') as infile:
    file1 = infile.readlines()
    constants = {i.split()[0]: i.split()[1] for i in file1[2:]}
```

I'm not getting it right with the `split()`, and I need a little correction!

Comment: Are your "constantts" separated with tabs ? If yes, the stdlib's `csv` module is your friend.

Comment: No they are regular spaces.

Comment: uhu, that's bad... is this supposed to be an end-user editable configuration file ???

Comment: No, that and similar files are just supposed to be converted into dictionaries for later use in other programs:))

Comment: Ok so it's a one shot script ? If yes, regexps are probably your best bet.

Comment: Yea i think i have it solved now with an easy one liner further down, thanks anyway!;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{' '.join(line.split()[:-2]):' '.join(line.split()[-2:]) for line in lines}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your text file I'm unable to get the correct value of no of spaces to split. So below code is designed to help you. Please have a look, it worked for you above stated file.

```
import string
valid_char = string.ascii_letters + ' '
valid_numbers = string.digits + '.'

constants = {}
with open('constants.txt') as file1:
    for line in file1.readlines():
        key = ''
        for index, char in enumerate(line):
            if char in valid_char:
                key += char
            else:
                key = key.strip()
                break
        value = ''

        for char in line[index:]:
            if char in valid_numbers:
                value += char
            else:
                break

        constants[key] = float(value)

print constants
```

Comment: That is quite nice, and it worked on the file im extracting, however i would hope there was something shorter!:)

Comment: Well yes its a long way :P we can easily make it short only if we know what will be the right value for split constant. For example if its 'tab', '\t' than your code will work fine with a little replacement in last line like this... constants = {i.split('\t')[0]: i.split('\t')[1] for i in file1[2:]}

Comment: @Thomas please answer the question in my comment above. If your file is a tab-separated-values then you __dont__ need any hand-written parsing code...

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried using regular expressions?
for example

```
([a-z]|\s)*
```

matches the first part of a line until the digits of the constants begin.

Python provides a very good tutorial on regular expressions (regex)
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

You can try out your regex online as well
https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

What about [re.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split)-

```
import re
lines = open(r"C:\txt.txt",'r').readlines()
for line in lines:
    data = re.split(r'\s{3,}',line)
    print "{0}  :  {1}".format(data[0],''.join(data[1:]))
```

Or use oneliner to make dictionary-

```
{k:v.strip() for k,v in [(re.split(r'\s{3,}',line)[0],''.join(re.split(r'\s{3,}',line)[1:])) for line in open(r"C:\txt.txt",'r').readlines() ]}
```

Output-

```
gravitational constant  :  6.67259e-11m**3/kg/s**2

Planck constant  :  6.6260755e-34J*s

elementary charge  :  1.60217733e-19C
```

Dictionary-

```
{'Planck constant': '6.6260755e-34J*s', 'elementary charge': '1.60217733e-19C', 'speed of light': '299792458.0m/s', 'gravitational constant': '6.67259e-11m**3/kg/s**2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('constants.txt', 'r') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    constants = {' '.join(line.split()[:-2]):float(' '.join(line.split()[-2:-1])) for line in lines[2:]}
```

Since there were two lines above not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This would best be solved using a regexp.

Focussing on your question (how to get the names) and your desires (have something shorter):

```
import re

# Regular expression fetches all characters
# until the first occurence of a number
REGEXP = re.compile('^([a-zA-Z\s]+)\d.*$')

with open('tst.txt', 'r') as f:

    for line in f:

        match = REGEXP.match(line)

        if match:

            # On a match the part between parentheses
            # are copied to the first group
            name = match.group(1).strip()

        else:

            # Raise something, or change regexp :)
            pass
```